# Home brew legalities South Africa

Tags: home-brewing

Good day everyone,

I write for The Citizen newspaper.

Mpumalanga Provincial Commissioner Lt General Mondli Zuma has stated it is illegal to home brew beer. I'd like to help correct him on this. If anyone is willing to speak to me on the record, I would appreciate it greatly.

I've read the "How to homebrew legally in South Africa?", however I need a bit more detail ([How to homebrew legally in South Africa?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/how-to-homebrew-legally-in-south-africa))

Please DM me your contact details and I'll call you asap.

Thank you.

Comment: If it is illegal, I'm sure there would be a law on the books. Have you tried https://www.lexisnexis.com/ or a South African equivalent?